# SvelteJS I added preferData to rollup.config.js, but it's ignored by vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, svelte, rollup

I added this in rollup.config.js

```
plugins: [
  svelte({
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ sourceMap: !production, scss: {
      prependData: "@import \"./src/scss/app.scss\";"
    }})
  }),
  ...etc
]
```

app.scss:

```
$v:red;
```

one of my svelte files:

```
value {
  color: $v
}
```

but vscode showed me this error:

```
Error: undefined variable

color: $v;
```

code is working fine, but what can i do to avoid vscode showing me this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you used the Svelte Rollup template, add a `svelte.config.js` next to your rollup config with the following

```js
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ scss: {
      prependData: "@import \"./src/scss/app.scss\";"
    }})
};
```

The Svelte for VS Code extension needs this file to understand what you are using besides Svelte itself in Svelte files. More info here: https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/in-general.md